# how to iterate this enum gives all values from none to west

Tags: c#-3.0

```
enum Orientation
{
    None = -1,
    North = 0,
    East = 1,
    South = 2,
    West = 3
}
```

how to iterate this enum gives all values from none to west

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
Orientation[] orientations = (Orientation[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Orientation));
```

Note that 0 is a more conventional value for `None`, as it will be the default value for any instance/static fields of type `Orientation`, as well as initial values in arrays etc.

EDIT: [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) is documented to return the values "sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants" - and I believe it's treating them as unsigned values.

There's a simple answer to this, fortunately:

```
Orientation[] orientations = (Orientation[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Orientation));
Array.Sort(orientations);
```

Comment: thanks Jon :) ya your suggestion is right to intialize enum default value by zero.But this is requirement in my project.my prob is Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumName)) returns array in which North is at zeroth position,East is at 1st south is at 2nd and west is at 3rd and none is at last.but i want None having value -1 be at zeroth  position.

Comment: @kk_guarav: That's actually *because* you've got None as -1 instead of 0 :) `Enum.GetValues` returns the values in *binary order* - and it sounds like that's the values as if they were unsigned. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Your large reputation just reminded me of the song "Bad reputation". Now it's stuck in my head. Thanks. :-|